Proof of Data Processing Inequality for f-divergence
Data processing inequality for $f$-divergence. For any Markov chain $X \to Y \to Z$, a pair of measures $P_{X,Y,Z}$ and $Q_{X,Y,Z}$ with a common Markov kernel $P_{Z|Y} = Q_{Z|Y}$, a convex map $f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}_+$, and an arbitrary function $g : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
D_f(P_{X,Y} \| Q_{X,Y}) \geq D_f(P_{X,Z} \| Q_{X,Z}) \geq D_f(P_{g(X,Z)} \| Q_{g(X,Z)}).
$$
How do I prove this inequality? I'm not able to convert the expectation in the first term $\int dP_{XY} \cdots$ to an expectation in the second term $\int dP_{YZ} \cdots$. I know that due to the Markov property we have $dP_{XYZ} = dP_X dP_{Y|X} dP_{Z|Y}$. I'm not sure how to use that here.
